# How to restrict dragging some elements in Flutter's RerderableListView

Tags: flutter, dart, drag-and-drop

I'd like some elements in RerderableListView to be non-draggable. I know I can do nothing in the `onReorder` function, but I want to deny start dragging.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrapped widgets I want to be non-draggable with `GestureDetector` and set empty handler `onLongPress: (){}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the elements with AbsorbPointer or IgnorePointer.

> **[AbsorbPointer class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html)**
>
> A widget that absorbs pointers during hit testing.
>
> When absorbing is true, this widget prevents its subtree from
> receiving pointer events by terminating hit testing at itself. It
> still consumes space during layout and paints its child as usual. It
> just prevents its children from being the target of located events,
> because it returns true from RenderBox.hitTest.

> **[IgnorePointer class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html)**
>
> A widget that is invisible during hit testing.
>
> When ignoring is true, this widget (and its subtree) is invisible to
> hit testing. It still consumes space during layout and paints its
> child as usual. It just cannot be the target of located events,
> because it returns false from RenderBox.hitTest.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to be able to handle taps on those elements.